# Images Being Squashed When Viewed In IE8

Tags: javascript, css, drupal, internet-explorer-8, image

Im working on a new website, http://blgz.co/, and for some weird reason, all my images are being squeezed!!!!!. I have spent the last few hours trying to solve the problem to no avail. Any help would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can't figure out why you're adding the max-width declaration to your global `img` tag. Remove that and all your images will flow normally:

```
img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%; /* remove */
}
```

Comment: It's also part of Bootstrap 2, they fixed it on 3 :)

Answer (score 4):

This is because of you `max-width: 100%` style, you're applying to `img` tag. In your case it is 23px only and this is because its parent `.node .field-name-field-op-main-image` has `float: left`, this means it will act as a inline element (but won't take into account width of you image or probably you set your image width later).
In other words remove either `float:left` or `max-width:100%` and you will get the "desired" result

Answer (score 3):

I'm late to this party, but I just ran into this issue myself, and simply removing `max-width` or not floating the parent element were not options. As a result, I had to find a *real* solution: just add `width:auto;`, e.g.:

```
img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

That ironically worked wonderfully in every browser *but* Chrome 20, which then began to behave as IE8 used to. So I resorted to a CSS hack to target IE8 only:

```
img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto\0/;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Now before everyone freaks out, I chose a CSS hack because I'm making this particular change in the Bootstrap CSS Framework's reset, which already uses hacks in other places. If you want to go the white-hat route, then you can simple add a conditional comment to your HTML:

```
<!--[if !IE 8]>
    <style type="text/css">
        img { width: auto; }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

One more note, if you're using the hack above in a *.less file, you have to escape it or the LESS compiler will choke on it:

```
width: e('auto\0/');
```

Comment: I think the conditional comment has to be without the !... <!--[if IE 8]>
    <style type="text/css">
        img { width: auto; }
    </style>
<![endif]-->

Answer (score 1):

In my case for some reason IE8 did not want to obey the explicit `width: 46px;` CSS.

Fix: Adding `min-width: 46px;` forces IE8 to render the correct width without breaking other browsers.